# Ruby on Rails Model with table join

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my database, I create three tables which are user, user_group, user_group_info.
I want to do something like this query, but i have no idea how can i join the two tables.

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN user_group AS ug ON u.user_group_id=ug.user_group_id
INNER JOIN user_group_info AS ugi ON ug.user_group_id=ugi.user_group_id
WHERE ugi.language_id = 1
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "user"
    self.primary_key = "user_id"
    belongs_to :user_group
end
```

---

UserGroup Model

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "user_group"
    self.primary_key = "user_group_id"
    has_many :user
    belongs_to :user_group_info
end
```

---

UserGroupInfo Model

```
class UserGroupInfo < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "user_group_info"
    has_many :user_group
end
```

Comment: Why do you make your table name singular?

Comment: user_group_info = It handle the user_group information with different language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ActiveRecord to create your query rather than creating it by hand. Try this:

```
User.joins(user_group: :user_group_info).where(user_group_infos: { language_id: 1 })
```

This should translate into what you gave as an example query in your question.

You start with `User` and you join with `user_groups`. Through `user_groups`, you join with `user_group_infos`. Finally, you add a condition on the `user_group_infos`. There are a couple ways to write that.

```
where("user_group_infos.language_id = ?", language_id)
# or
where(user_group_infos: { language_id: language_id })
```

Comment: It help me a lot, i know what is the problem now, thank you.